# Reactive unputs with actionbutton in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to have an ractive shiny app with an actionbuttion, ie I want to automaticly show the choice dependeing in each last choice.
For example if I choose "A" in the filter 1 I want to show "1", "27" and "All" choice in filter 2 without actionate the "go" button

Here is my code :

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Title"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width=3,
                 selectInput("filter1", "Filter 1", multiple = TRUE, choices = c("All", LETTERS)),
                 selectInput("filter2", "Filter 2", multiple = TRUE, choices = c("All", as.character(seq.int(1, length(letters), 1)))),
                 selectInput("filter3", "Filter 3", multiple = TRUE, choices = c("All", letters)),
                 actionButton("go_button", "GO !")),

    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("tableprint")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  goButton <- eventReactive(input$go_button,{
    # Data
    df <- tibble(LETTERS = rep(LETTERS, 2), Numbers = as.character(1:52),
                 letters = paste(LETTERS, Numbers, sep = ""))

    df1 <- df

    if("All" %in% input$filter1){
      df1
    } else if (length(input$filter1)){
      df1 <- df1[which(df1$LETTERS %in% input$filter1),]
    }

    # Update selectInput choices based on the filtered data. Update 'selected' to reflect the user input.
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter1", choices = c("All", df$LETTERS), selected = input$filter1)
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter2", choices = c("All", df1$Numbers), selected = input$filter2)



    if("All" %in% input$filter2){
      df1
    } else if (length(input$filter2)){
      df1 <- df1[which(df1$Numbers %in% input$filter2),]
    }
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter3", choices = c("All", df1$letters), selected = input$filter3)

    if("All" %in% input$filter3){
      df1
    } else if (length(input$filter3)){
      df1 <- df1[which(df1$letters %in% input$filter3),]
    }
    datatable(df1)
  })

  output$tableprint <- DT::renderDataTable({
    goButton()

  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44570404/updating-filters-in-shiny-app/44639701#44639701

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code so that the select input and table is reactive and gets updated when you change any select input.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Title"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width=3,
                 selectInput("filter1", "Filter 1", multiple = FALSE, choices = c("All", LETTERS), selected = "All"),
                 selectInput("filter2", "Filter 2", multiple = FALSE, choices = c("All", as.character(seq.int(1, length(letters), 1))), selected = "All"),
                 selectInput("filter3", "Filter 3", multiple = FALSE, choices = c("All", letters), selected = "All"),
                 actionButton("go_button", "GO !")),

    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("tableprint")
    )
  )
)



df <- tibble(LETTERS = rep(LETTERS, 2), Numbers = as.character(1:52),
             letters = paste(LETTERS, Numbers, sep = ""))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data1 <- reactive({

    if("All" %in% input$filter1){
      df1 <- df
    }else{
      df1 <- df[which(df$LETTERS %in% input$filter1),]
    }

    df1
  })

  data2 <- reactive({

    if("All" %in% input$filter2){
      df1 <- data1()
    } else if (length(input$filter2)){
      df1 <- data1()[which(data1()$Numbers %in% input$filter2),]
    }
    df1
  })

  data3<- reactive({

    if("All" %in% input$filter3){
      df1 <- data2()
    } else if (length(input$filter3)){
      df1 <- data2()[which(data2()$letters %in% input$filter3),]
    }
    df1
  })


  observeEvent(input$filter1,{
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter2", choices = c("All", data1()$Numbers), selected = "All")
  })

  observeEvent(input$filter2,{
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter3", choices = c("All", data2()$letters), selected = "All")
  })

  output$tableprint <- DT::renderDataTable({
    data3()

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

To render the table only button click you can use the following server code instead of the above:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data1 <- reactive({

    if("All" %in% input$filter1){
      df1 <- df
    }else{
      df1 <- df[which(df$LETTERS %in% input$filter1),]
    }

    df1
  })

  data2 <- reactive({

    if("All" %in% input$filter2){
      df1 <- data1()
    } else if (length(input$filter2)){
      df1 <- data1()[which(data1()$Numbers %in% input$filter2),]
    }
    df1
  })

  data3<- reactive({

    if("All" %in% input$filter3){
      df1 <- data2()
    } else if (length(input$filter3)){
      df1 <- data2()[which(data2()$letters %in% input$filter3),]
    }
    df1
  })


  observeEvent(input$filter1,{
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter2", choices = c("All", data1()$Numbers), selected = "All")
  })

  observeEvent(input$filter2,{
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter3", choices = c("All", data2()$letters), selected = "All")
  })

  observeEvent(input$go_button,{
    output$tableprint <- DT::renderDataTable({
      data3()

    })
  })     
}
```

In the above code you will notice that after it renders for the first time it gets updated automatically when we change the value of selectinput. To avoid that and get the new table rendered only in the end the code below can be used:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data3<-NULL
  data1 <- reactive({

    if("All" %in% input$filter1){
      df1 <- df
    }else{
      df1 <- df[which(df$LETTERS %in% input$filter1),]
    }

    df1
  })

  data2 <- reactive({

    if("All" %in% input$filter2){
      df1 <- data1()
    } else if (length(input$filter2)){
      df1 <- data1()[which(data1()$Numbers %in% input$filter2),]
    }
    df1
  })


  observeEvent(input$filter1,{
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter2", choices = c("All", data1()$Numbers), selected = "All")
  })

  observeEvent(input$filter2,{
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter3", choices = c("All", data2()$letters), selected = "All")
    if("All" %in% input$filter3){
      data3 <<- data2()
    } else if (length(input$filter3)){
      data3 <<- data2()[which(data2()$letters %in% input$filter3),]
    }

  })

  observeEvent(input$go_button,{
    output$tableprint <- DT::renderDataTable({
      data3

    })
  })

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry @DimitriPetrenko. I seemed to have copied an incorrect code. Can you check now? Just to make things more clear I have made the `selectinput` parameter `multiple = FALSE`, it works otherwise also. Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for responding back, I need to show the table only if il actionate the go button, in your case the table is updated automatically.

Comment: @DimitriPetrenko, I have added a code  so that the table renders only if the action go button is clicked. Hope it helps!