# Updating filters in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have an app with updating filters but seems not to work correctly I can't fix it. I want all filters updating when I change a depending filter
I think the problem is about observeEvent 
Thanks for help

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

VG <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "A")
AG <- c(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1)
AP <- letters[1:7]
AK <- paste(VG, AG, AP, sep = "-")
data <- data.frame(VG, AG, AP, AK)

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(3,
         selectInput("VG", label = h4("VG.ETD"),choices = unique(data$VG)),
         selectInput("AG", label = h4("AG.ETD"),choices = unique(data$AG))),
  column(3,
         selectInput("AP", label = h4("AP.ETD"),choices = unique(data$AP)),
         selectInput("AK", label = h4("AK.ETD"),choices = unique(data$AK)),
         actionButton("go", "GO")),
  column(6,DT::dataTableOutput("dtt"))
)

server<-function(input,output,session){

  observeEvent(input$VG,{
    updateSelectInput(session, 'AG', choices = unique(data$AG[data$VG %in% input$VG]))
  })

  observeEvent(input$AG,{
    updateSelectInput(session, 'AP', choices = unique(data$AP[data$AG %in% input$AG &
                                                                data$VG %in% input$VG]))
  })

  observeEvent(input$AP,{
    updateSelectInput(session, 'AK', choices = unique(data$AK[data$AP %in% input$AP &
                                                                data$AG %in% input$AG &
                                                                data$VG %in% input$VG]))
  })

  df <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    data %>% filter(VG %in% input$VG, 
                    AG %in% input$AG,
                    AP %in% input$AP,
                    AK %in% input$AK)

  })

  output$dtt <- DT::renderDataTable({
    df()

  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: What exactly is a "depending filter"? What's the behavior you want here? I'm not sure I understand the problem form your description.

Comment: for example when I change the VG or "B", the AK ETD doesn't update, still give me A-1-a

Comment: I need something like 'obserEvent(input$AP | input$AG | input$VG, ...)'

Comment: You can [observe more than one event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731975/how-to-listen-for-more-than-one-event-expression-within-a-shiny-eventreactive-ha)

Comment: Also, you can (should) render the UI in the server side to produce updated input options.

Comment: Thanks for help, I I updated my code and filters work fine, I want to add "All_VG" for VG filter, "All_AG" for AG filter ...i tried something but unfortunately no results

Comment: Don't edit a question to ask a different question. Start a new post instead.

Comment: OK thanks i did it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You posted a comment on my post saying that you were having the same problem as me. It looks a little bit different, but I found a solution to my problem so I've posted the code below in case it helps you at all.

```
l <- NULL
l$name <- c('b','e','d','b','b','d','e','e','b','b')
l$age <- c(20,20,21,21,20,22,22,30,21,32)
l$gender <- c('Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male','Male', 
'Female','Male',"Female","Male")
l <- as.data.frame(l)
l$name <- as.character(l$name)
l$age <- as.numeric(l$age)
l$gender <- as.character(l$gender)


library(shiny)
server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){

assign('All Names',unique(sort(l$name)))
assign("All Ages", unique(sort(l$age)))
assign('All Genders', unique(sort(l$gender)))
data1 <- reactive(l[which(l$name %in% if(exists(input$name))
{get(input$name)}else{input$name}),])

output$table1 <- renderTable(data1())
output$text1 <- renderPrint(input$name)
data2 <- reactive(data1()[which(data1()$age %in% if(exists(input$age))
{get(input$age)}else{input$age}),])
output$table2 <- renderTable(data2())
data3 <- reactive(data2()[which(data2()$gender %in% if(exists(input$gender))
{get(input$gender)}else{input$gender}),])

output$table3 <- renderTable(data3())


output$Box1 =  renderUI(
if((is.null(input$age)) & (is.null(input$gender))){
  selectInput("name", "Choose Name", choices=c("All Names",unique(sort(l$name))), selected = input$name)
} else{selectInput("name", "Choose Name", choices=c("All Names",unique(l[l$gender %in% (if(exists(input$gender)){get(input$gender)}else{input$gender}) & l$age %in% (if(exists(input$age)){get(input$age)}else{input$age}) , "name"])), selected = input$name)
}
)



output$Box2 =  renderUI(
if((is.null(input$name)) & (is.null(input$gender))){
  selectInput("age", "Choose Age", choices=c("All Ages", unique(sort(l$age))), selected = input$age)
}else{selectInput("age", "Choose Age", choices=c("All Ages",unique(l[l$gender %in% (if(exists(input$gender)){get(input$gender)}else{input$gender}) & l$name %in% (if(exists(input$name)){get(input$name)}else{input$name}) , "age"])), selected = input$age)}
)

output$Box3 =  renderUI(
  if((is.null(input$name)) & (is.null(input$age))){
    selectInput("gender", "Choose Gender", choices=c("All Genders", unique(sort(l$gender))), selected = input$gender)
  }else{

    selectInput("gender", "Choose Gender", choices=c("All Genders", unique(l[l$name %in% (if(exists(input$name)){get(input$name)}else{input$name}) & l$age %in% (if(exists(input$age)){get(input$age)}else{input$age}), "gender"])), selected = input$gender, multiple = TRUE)
  }
)



})

ui <-shinyUI(fluidPage(
uiOutput("Box1"),
uiOutput("Box2"),
uiOutput("Box3"),
tableOutput("table3")
))

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: thanks I want the selectinput reactive and your code is doing it finegood but I need an "go" button for updating the output table ( because I have some problem to fix reactivity with actionbutton) have you an idea for this ? thks

Comment: ` data3 <- eventReactive(input$go_baba, {
    data2()[which(data2()$gender %in% if(exists(input$gender))
    {get(input$gender)}else{input$gender}),]
  })` do the job thanks

Comment: I edited the code to allow multiple = TRUE. The output$Box3 needed to have an if statement added to it

Comment: Can you avoid the error message when you dont choose input : `invalid first argument`

Answer (score 2):

I answered to a similar question that you commented (saying you've got the same problem) with this solution :

```
l <- NULL
l$name <- c('b','e','d','b','b','d','e')
l$age <- c(20,20,21,21,20,22,22)
l <- as.data.frame(l)
l$name <- as.character(l$name)
l$age <- as.numeric(l$age)
library(shiny)

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output, session){

  data1 <- reactive({
    if(input$Box1 == "All"){
      l
    }else{
      l[which(l$name == input$Box1),]
    }
  })

  data2 <- reactive({
    if (input$Box2 == "All"){
      l
    }else{
      l[which(l$age == input$Box2),]
    }
  })

  observe({

    if(input$Box1 != "All"){
      updateSelectInput(session,"Box2","Choose an age", choices = c("All",unique(data1()$age)))
    }

    else if(input$Box2 != 'All'){
      updateSelectInput(session,"Box1","Choose a name", choices = c('All',unique(data2()$name)))
    }

    else if (input$Box1 == "All" & input$Box2 == "All"){
      updateSelectInput(session,"Box2","Choose an age", choices = c('All',unique(l$age)))
      updateSelectInput(session,"Box1","Choose a name", choices = c('All',unique(l$name)))
    }
  })


  data3 <- reactive({
    if(input$Box2 == "All"){
      data1()
    }else if (input$Box1 == "All"){
      data2()
    }else if (input$Box2 == "All" & input$Box1 == "All"){
      l
    }
    else{
      l[which(l$age== input$Box2 & l$name == input$Box1),]
    }
  })

  output$table1 <- renderTable({
    data3()
  })


})



ui <-shinyUI(fluidPage(
  selectInput("Box1","Choose a name", choices = c("All",unique(l$name))),
  selectInput("Box2","Choose an age", choices = c("All",unique(l$age))),
  tableOutput("table1")
))

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: How can I get multiple = True in selectInput cause doesnt seem to work ?

Comment: any other approach as it seems to be a perfect solution for 2 or 3 filters but incase we have more than 5 filters code becomes very complex.