# Adding "All values" in my inputs filters in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

My app is working good but I want to add a choice which allow to users to choose all values of a variable.
For example, for the first filter, I want something like "All" where "A", "B" and "C" are included.
And the same thing with other filters, I tried many tricks but I couldn't fix this.
Any help will be appreciated

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

VG <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "A")
AG <- c(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1)
AP <- letters[1:7]
AK <- paste(VG, AG, AP, sep = "-")
data <- data.frame(VG, AG, AP, AK)

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(3,
         selectInput("VG", label = h4("VG.ETD"), choices = unique(data$VG)),
         selectInput("AG", label = h4("AG.ETD"), choices = unique(data$AG))),
  column(3,
         selectInput("AP", label = h4("AP.ETD"), choices = unique(data$AP)),
         selectInput("AK", label = h4("AK.ETD"), choices = unique(data$AK)),
         actionButton("go", "GO")),
  column(6,DT::dataTableOutput("dtt"))
)

server<-function(input,output,session){



  observeEvent(input$VG,{
    updateSelectInput(session, 'AG', choices = unique(data$AG[data$VG %in% input$VG]))
  })

  observeEvent(c(input$VG, input$AG),{
    updateSelectInput(session, 'AP', choices = unique(data$AP[data$AG %in% input$AG &
                                                              data$VG %in% input$VG]))
  })

  observeEvent(c(input$VG, input$AG, input$AP), {
    updateSelectInput(session, 'AK', choices = unique(data$AK[data$AP %in% input$AP &
                                                              data$AG %in% input$AG &
                                                              data$VG %in% input$VG]))
  })

  df <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    data %>% filter(VG %in% input$VG, 
                    AG %in% input$AG,
                    AP %in% input$AP,
                    AK %in% input$AK)

  })

  output$dtt <- DT::renderDataTable({
    df()

  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Perhaps change choices to:  c('All',unique(data$VG)), and then create a new reactive variable that looks at the input of that selectinput.  Have an if statement that says if(input$X == 'All'){c('A','B','C')}else{input$X}.  Then pass that reactive variable to your filter.  Also there is a multiple = TRUE, argument to selectinput which allows the user to select more than one selection.

Comment: solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44570404/updating-filters-in-shiny-app/44639701#44639701

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve a similar problem in the past I used the following approach:

1. created a vector with the names of the filter options I wanted to use (in this case, "All states" as well as the actual unique variables in the column **State** of data frame **rudd**)

   ```
   states <- c("All states", levels(rudd$State))
   ```
2. used the values of the vector as possible input in an input panel (states[1] (="All states") is the default selection)

   ```
   selectInput("state", "Choose a state:", choices = states, selected = states[1])
   ```
3. created a conditional statement to select the right subset of data to display, according to user input (and proceed with passing a temporary, subseted table to the reactive output)

   ```
   library("dplyr")

   dat <- reactive({
       if (input$State!="All states"){ 
       temp <- state_map %>%
       filter(State== tolower(input$State)) 
   } else { 
       temp <- state_map[1,] 
   }
   })
   ```

In other words, if a specific state is selected, then the data frame is filtered based on this selection, otherwise all rows will be passed to the interactive output.

The entire code is here: https://github.com/DrRadan/RiskEcon-Shiny-App/blob/master/Health.Rmd
and its implementation here: https://rdna.shinyapps.io/Health/

I hope this is of some help.