# In shiny, how to link the filter to part of the data to change some of the charts and not others?

Tags: r, filter, shiny

I am trying to visualise the data from Santander's Product recommendation comp.  I want to show distributions of the variables with different filters, to identify where there might be variables which might be indicative of change.  I am new to RShiny.
I can get the app to work, when I define the filters before hand and don't have the dashboard linked to those filters.  As soon as I try to link it, I get an error

> "Warning: Error in [: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

I've looked this up and don't see in the additional code where I am referencing something that R thinks is a function.

The area that is failing is where I try to define the second dataset for which I am filtering on.

```
df2<-reactive({df2<-df %>% filter(Changed %>% input$Changed)})
```

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240434/r-shiny-error-object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable) for the error message but see nothing that is named "Changed" or df2 in R

I lifted [this piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44592200/adding-all-values-in-my-inputs-filters-in-shiny-app) to allow for All in the selection.. but I've removed this element and I still have this issue.

```
library(shiny)
#df<-trainchange
df<-data.frame(age=c(56, 63, 62, 62, 60, 49, 50, 62, 60, 57)
           ,
           Num_Changes= c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
           Changed=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1))
#rng<- c("All",unique(df$Changed))
rng<- c(unique(df$Changed))

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Data science FTW!"),
    sidebarPanel(
            h3('Sidebar text'),
            selectInput('Changed', 'Have New Products Been Bought', 
choices=rng, selected= rng[1])
    ),
    mainPanel(
            h3('Main Panel text'),
            fluidRow(
                    splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"), 
plotOutput("newHist"), plotOutput("newHist3"))
            ),
            fluidRow(
                    splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"), 
plotOutput("newHist2"), plotOutput("newHist4"))
            )
            )
))

library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

df<-data.frame(age=c(56, 63, 62, 62, 60, 49, 50, 62, 60, 57)
            ,
            Num_Changes= c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
            Changed=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1))

# df<-trainchange

#it works when I define this and block the element of code that
#is not working, but then its just static charts
#df2<-df[df$Num_Changes!=0,]

#list will grow
var3<-c("age","Num_Changes")
shinyServer(
    function(input, output) {

#this is the part that cause the failure

            df2<-reactive({
                    df2<-df %>% filter(Changed %>% input$Changed)
                    # if(input$Changed=="All")
                    #         return()
                    # df
             })

            output$newHist <- renderPlot({
                    hist(df[,var3[1]], xlab=var1, 
col='lightblue',main='Histogram') })
            output$newHist3 <- renderPlot({
                    hist(df2[,var3[1]], xlab=var3[1], 
col='blue',main='Histogram') })
            output$newHist2 <- renderPlot({
                    hist(df[,var3[2]], xlab=var3[2], 
col='red',main='Histogram')})
            output$newHist4 <- renderPlot({
                    hist(df2[,var3[2]], xlab=var3[2], 
col='purple',main='Histogram')

              })
    }
)
```

I cannot upload the image, but it should have two histograms of the same variable next to each other, and the one on the right has a different filter as determined by the sidebar.  Once I get this working, I will expand to more filters, and more charts.
Thanks for any help you can give.
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need `%in%` instead of `%>%` inside `filter` for `filter(Changed %>% input$Changed)`. Second, `reactive` is a function so any `reactive` object should be called later using `()` so `df2` become `df2()`. Finally, I changed xlab from `var1` to `var3[1]` in the first plot.

Here is a working `server` function.

```
 shinyServer(
    function(input, output) {

      #this is the part that cause the failure

      df2<-reactive({
        df2<-df %>% filter(Changed %in% input$Changed)
        # if(input$Changed=="All")
        #         return()
        # df
      })
      observe(print(df2()))
      output$newHist <- renderPlot({
        hist(df[,var3[1]], xlab=var3[1], 
             col='lightblue',main='Histogram') })
      output$newHist3 <- renderPlot({
        hist(df2()[,var3[1]], xlab=var3[1], 
             col='blue',main='Histogram') })
      output$newHist2 <- renderPlot({
        hist(df[,var3[2]], xlab=var3[2], 
             col='red',main='Histogram')})
      output$newHist4 <- renderPlot({
        hist(df2()[,var3[2]], xlab=var3[2], 
             col='purple',main='Histogram')

      })
    }
  )
```

## Edit

```
rng<- c("All",unique(df$Changed))
df2<-reactive({
        #df2<-df %>% filter(Changed %in% input$Changed)
        if(input$Changed=="All") df else df %>% filter(Changed %in% input$Changed)
      })
```

Comment: Thank you for this, and the explanation of where I was going wrong.  I am now struggling to get the "All" element to work.  In my UI i create a range rng for the Changed variable, and I've changed the default to be rng[2] so it runs.  As soon as I select All, I get an error message saying "invalid number of breaks".  I have tried using an if(is.null) statement in the server function but I then receive a much bigger error and the app crashes immediately.  Thanks for the help.  It is helping me learn

Comment: I got around my issue by adding multiple = TRUE to my select input.  Thanks for the help again.

Comment: @JamesOliver it's my pleasure to help. Please see my edit for a more robust way in 'All' case.